# Strange number of handles in WaitForMultipleObjectsEx

Tags: .net, windbg, sos

Looking the output of kb, this thread is waiting for some event. Now the first argument for this method is number of handles its waiting for but as you can in the output it has a value of 0024e154. I usually see a number like2, 3, 4 etc. Any ideas what does this mean?

```
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child  
0024e1a0 75c70208 0024e154 0024e1c8 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x11d
```

Comment: +0x11d, that's too far into the function to assume you're looking at a reliable call stack.  No Windows version mentioned either, no way to check.

Comment: what does +0x11d indicate here? The process was running on 32-bit Windows Vista

Answer (score 0):

The call stack does not look reliable. A couple of questions:

- The correct symbols have been loaded?
- If the correct symbols have been loaded the best approach is to look at the raw stack trace. You can do this by determining wehre the stack starts and ends. This can be determined with

  !teb

  Look for ExceptionBase and ExceptionLimit output and then dump the raw stack with

  dps begin end

  and analyze the stack

Answer (score 0):

+0x11d is offset from WaitForMultipleObjectsEx. Windbg take the nearest symbol, and when you see a such large offset, it usually mean that you don’t have good symbols. The stack frame are probably not in **WaitForMultipleObjectsEx** at all and therefore the parameters seems nonsense.
Do a

```
 .symfix
 .reload
```

before looking at your  stack again.
If you see the:

```
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
```

you can’t trust the output.